# Batch file - Remap printer connections

Tags: batch-file, printing

Hoping someone could help.....

I need to try and automate the remapping of user profiles print queues from two 'old' to 'new' print servers. There are 1000s of clients, each with a variety of queues from either or both old print servers, no consistent approach for deployment was used.

Each new print server has a replica set of queues from the one its taking over from, achieved simply by using export/import from print management.

All queues have been added by end users, they have rights to add/remove queues. Group Policy was not used to deploy, so utilizing it to 're'deploy is not feasible unfortunately.

I've got a batch file that I've cobbled together which works, however its quite slow given the volume of print queues (circa 350 between the two servers) it needs to run through.

The logic is quite simple, it places all queues from the old servers into an Array, then checks what is installed in the local reg hive on the client computers in HKCU\printers\connections. If it finds a match, it then add the same queue from the new server and deletes the old queue.

Like I said, the following 'does work', but having to run through the 350 odd queues line by line takes approx 30secs per server to complete.

I'm not a scripting person (which I'm sure you've figured out lol), but would be very grateful for anyone who could suggest a better way to code this in order for it to be more efficient in its processing?

In the below I've only listed 5 queues for ease of viewing, but in the actual script there are circa 350 queues.

```
@echo off

REM Define Variables
SET oldserver=2008_PRN1
SET newserver=2016_PRN1
SET oldserver2=2008_PRN2
SET newserver2=2016-PRN2

REM Create Array
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set pqueue[0]=PS1-Printer1
set pqueue[1]=PS2-Printer2
set pqueue[2]=PS1-Printer3
set pqueue[3]=PS2-Printer4
set pqueue[4]=PS1-Printer5



REM - FIRST SERVER - Loop through local registry and Array, add/remove queues as found
for /l %%n in (0,1,4) do ( 
  For /F "Tokens=4 delims=\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Connections ^|find /I ",,%oldserver%,!pqueue[%%n]!"') DO (
    rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n"\\%newserver%\!pqueue[%%n]!"
    For /F "Tokens=4 delims=\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Connections ^|find /I ",,%oldserver%,!pqueue[%%n]!"') DO (
      rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /dn /q /n"\\%oldserver%\!pqueue[%%n]!"
    )  
  )
)

REM - SECOND SERVER - Loop through local registry and Array, add/remove queues as found
for /l %%n in (0,1,4) do ( 
  For /F "Tokens=4 delims=\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Connections ^|find /I ",,%oldserver2%,!pqueue[%%n]!"') DO (
    rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /in /q /n"\\%newserver2%\!pqueue[%%n]!"
    For /F "Tokens=4 delims=\" %%I In ('reg query HKCU\Printers\Connections ^|find /I ",,%oldserver2%,!pqueue[%%n]!"') DO (
      rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /dn /q /n"\\%oldserver2%\!pqueue[%%n]!"
    )  
  )
)

:quit
```

Comment: Use PowerShell if you want quicker results.